# Mysql time stamp queries

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have a column that uses time stamp. My question is I am a bit confused about how to make queries against it,how would I say

Where $time is after X date

Are queries made in local time or CUT?

When I just try to do where andthe post date /time I get an error because of the space and if I quote it I think it takes it as a string : /

What format do I use for the date in the WHERE clauss !?!?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the normal logical comparisons, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date >= '2010-01-31'
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date >= '2010-01-31 12:01:01'
```

Time is generally in your current local time, but you can run the query "SELECT CURTIME()" to check.  Also, make sure you have the year-month-date in the right order... that can cause issues.

The manual has more details:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you talk about TIMESTAMP column type (not Unix timestamp) the format is either `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'` (quoted) or `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS`

Atually, in the first case you can use any spearators you wish (or none), only numbers are taken into ccount

Comment: this would have been higher voted if it had a dummy prof example, like the other one. 

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE date >= 20100131`

I like that you can just use numbers, thumbs up